# Want to add multiple videos in single page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Actually I want to incooperate multiple videos in a single xml file .But while adding I am getting error.
Actually I am confused why the error has occurred.So I have attached my java  code below .The part which i wrote in bold Im getting error over there.I want to add mutiple videos in one page.So I was trying that.

```
public class bvideos extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bvideos);

        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);
        String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bvideo1;

        VideoView **videoView** = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);
        String **videoPath** = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bvideo1;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);





    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to show all videos at same time? why not you use recycler view if it is so?

Comment: No,I dont want to play all videos at a time.whenever we will click on that it will play

Comment: for me recyclerview is difficult .can u please suggest excluding that,so that it can be easy for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
// make an array or Uri data type and add uri's in it
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // get video from next index and set to video view  
  }
}, new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // get video from previous index and set to video view
  }
});

videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

Comment: Actually I tried your code,but its giving me an error over VideoView.setMediaController(mc);

Comment: What should I do ??

Comment: Can u suggest me solution

Comment: can you please share the error log?

Comment: yaa .........sure.will share